# Seding date as json response from web api to angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

Very simple question.

I am working on a angularjs app retrieving data from an asp.net web api. I have a date field (ThisDate) in a table (Model) which has date format like this -

`2015-03-14 12:39:32.470`

When I send this as a response json string from asp.net -

```
string json = "{\"CreatedAt\": \"" + Model.ThisDate + "\"}";
response.Content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
```

..I am getting it like this in angularjs app -

`14-03-2015 12:39:32`

And When I send it as a json serialized object from asp.net -

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)
```

..I am getting it like this in angularjs app -

`2015-03-14T12:39:32.470`

What are the reasons for this to be different? I want both to be in second format, so sorting works correctly. How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why it converts they way it does. But I was able to fix this by specifying a sortable datetime format while sending response json string as below -

```
string json = "{\"CreatedAt\": \"" + Model.ThisDate.ToString("s") + "\"}";
```

Refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)